# Php serialize() values to comma separated string values

Tags: php, serialization

Hello i am trying to convert PHP serialize strings into comma separated values for a absolutely absurd client requirement :P Here's the code!!!

```
$o = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$l = serialize($o);
$o = [$l,$l,$l];
echo '<pre>';
$m = array();
print_r($o);
echo '-----------------------------------' . '<br>';
for($i=0;$i<count($o);$i++)
{
$d = unserialize($o[$i]);
$y = '';

for($q=0;$q<count($d);$q++)
{
$r = $d[$q] ;
$y = $y.$r.',';
//echo $r . ',';
}
//echo $y;

array_push($m,$y);

//echo '<br>';
}
print_r($m);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to get rid of the trailing comma?

Comment: Trying to convert a column on my db which contains all serialized values. and save them back in the form of comma separated values actually! The trailing comma isn't quite a problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I were your, I would use `implode` to serialize strings into comma separated values.
I've modified you code to this:

```
$o = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$l = serialize($o);
$o = array($l,$l,$l);
echo '<pre>';
$m = array();
print_r($o);
echo '-----------------------------------' . '<br>';
for($i=0;$i<count($o);$i++)
{
        $d = unserialize($o[$i]);

        // using implode for briefer
        $m[] = implode(',', $d);
}
print_r($m);
```